# Multilined itemRenderer for a spark.components.List - with test case and screenshot

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, itemrenderer, multiline, itemrenderers

In the simple Flex 4 web application below -

[image]

is it possible to change the custom item renderer `MyRenderer`, so that it wraps the too long lines?

**TestApp.mxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayList;

            private static const MONTHS:ArrayList = new ArrayList([
                "1 January is a beautyful month", 
                "2 February is a beautyful month", 
                "3 March is a beautyful month", 
                "4 April is a beautyful month", 
                "5 May is a beautyful month", 
                "6 June is a beautyful month", 
                "7 July is a beautyful month", 
                "8 August is a beautyful month", 
                "9 September is a beautyful month", 
                "10 October is a beautyful month", 
                "11 November is a beautyful month",
                "12 December is a beautyful month"
            ]);
        ]]>

    </fx:Script>

    <s:List id="myList"
            width="60"
            dataProvider="{MONTHS}"
            itemRenderer="MyRenderer" /> 
</s:Application>
```

**MyRenderer.mxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    autoDrawBackground="false">

    <fx:Script> 
        <![CDATA[    
            [Bindable]
            public var myColor:uint = 0xFFFFFF;

            override public function set label(value:String):void 
            { 
                super.label = value; 
                labelDisplay.text = label; 

            // var list:List = owner as List;
            // if (list)
                // labelDisplay.width = list.width;

                if (label.indexOf("June") >= 0)
                    myColor = 0xFF0000;
                else if (label.indexOf("July") >= 0)
                    myColor = 0x00FF00;
                else if (label.indexOf("August") >= 0)
                    myColor = 0x0000FF;
                else 
                    myColor = 0xFFFFFF;
            } 
        ]]> 
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Rect width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="{myColor}" />
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

    <s:Label id="labelDisplay" />
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I need same as in the [Creating multi-line list rows with variable row heights](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/10/27/creating-multi-line-list-rows-with-variable-row-heights/) blog - but for the [spark.components.List](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/List.html) which doesn't have the `wordWrap` property anymore.

**UPDATE 3:**

Actually after RIAStar answered my question (thanks!), my problems have just started - when I now call the `myList.ensureIndexIsVisible(MONTHS.length - 1);` it doesn't really scroll to the bottom.

I have prepared a new question: [List with multilined (word wrapping) item renderer - how to scroll to the bottom? With test case and screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044811/list-with-multilined-word-wrapping-item-renderer-how-to-scroll-to-the-bottom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [VerticalLayout](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/layouts/VerticalLayout.html)'s [variableRowHeight](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/layouts/VerticalLayout.html#variableRowHeight) property for that. Something like this:

```
<s:List id="myList" width="60" dataProvider="{MONTHS}" itemRenderer="MyRenderer">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout variableRowHeight="true" 
                          horizontalAlign="justify" 
                          requestedMinRowCount="5"/>
    </s:layout>
</s:List>
```

Furthermore, the Label in your ItemRenderer can take up all the horizontal space it wants. You should constrain its `width`. For example:

```
<s:Label width="100%"/>
```

Comment: Hmm, doesn't change anything. Should the `layout` maybe be set for the `MyRenderer`?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber I think because your Label can stretch as far to the right as it wants. Try setting its width to 100%.

Comment: That's odd, cause I've already done this succesfully. I'll try to get you a working example.

Comment: Allright, `<s:Label id="labelDisplay" width="100%" />` and `<s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="justify" />` do the trick! Thanks for the pointers