# Multiline and wordWrap in a List component?

Tags: list, actionscript-3, multiline, word-wrap

I am writing a flash/as3 project which contains a list component.
What I need to know is how to add multiline and wordWrap property for large text.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949378/multilined-itemrenderer-for-a-spark-components-list-with-test-case-and-screens] may it can help you

Comment: Well that didn't help but I 'm glad that I won't use that list. Employer wants buttons and he didn't like the List idea.Thanks anyways :)